# Shortest path question involving transfer in cyclic graph

Tags: c++, graph, shortest-path

I'm trying to solve a problem of graph:
There are (n+1) cities(no. from 0 to n), and (m+1) bus lines(no. from 0 to m).
(A line may contain repeated cities, meaning the line have a **cycle**.)
Each line covers several cities, and it takes **t_ij** to run from city i to city j (t_ij may differ in different lines).
Moreover, it takes extra **transfer_time** to each time you get in a bus.

An edge look like this: city i --(time)-->city2
**Example1**:
n = 2, m = 2, start = 0, end = 2
line0: 
0 --(1)--> 1 --(1)--> 2; transfer_time = 1
line1:
0 --(2)--> 2; transfer_time = 2
Line0 take 1+1+1 = 3 and line1 takes 4, so the min is 3.

**Example2**:
n = 4, m = 0, start = 0, end = 4
line0:
0 --(2)--> 1 --(3)--> 2 --(3)-->3 --(3)--> 1 --(2)--> 4; transfer_time = 1
it takes 1(get in at 0) + 2(from 0 to 1) + 1(get off and get in, transfer) + 2 = 6

I've tried to solve it with Dijkstra Algorithm, but failed to handle graph with cycles(like Example2).
Below is my code.

```
struct Edge {
    int len;
    size_t line_no;
};

class Solution {

public:
    Solution() = default;

    //edges[i][j] is a vector, containing ways from city i to j in different lines
    int findNearestWay(vector<vector<vector<Edge>>>& edges, vector<int>& transfer_time, size_t start, size_t end) {
        size_t n = edges.size();
        vector<pair<int, size_t>> distance(n, { INT_MAX / 2, -1 }); //first: len, second: line_no
        distance[start].first = 0;
        vector<bool> visited(n);
        int cur_line = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int next_idx = -1;
            //find the nearest city
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                if (!visited[j] && (next_idx == -1 || distance[j].first < distance[next_idx].first))
                    next_idx = j;
            }
            visited[next_idx] = true;
            cur_line = distance[next_idx].second;
            //update distance of other cities
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                for (const Edge& e : edges[next_idx][j]) {
                    int new_len = distance[next_idx].first + e.len;
                    //transfer
                    if (cur_line == -1 || cur_line != e.line_no) {
                        new_len += transfer_time[e.line_no];
                    }
                    if (new_len < distance[j].first) {
                        distance[j].first = new_len;
                        distance[j].second = e.line_no;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return distance[end].first == INT_MAX / 2 ? -1 : distance[end].first;
    }
};
```

Is there a better practice to work out it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The name is cycles, not circles. Have another look at your visited flag, I haven't fully analyzed your code but I have doubts. Debug your code step by step and see if each step produces the results you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've corrected them. By and large, I use Dijkstra; the elements in distance array have an extra tag(pair's second) to show by which way I arrive a city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `visited` set looks wrong.  The "nodes" you would feed into Djikstra's algorithm cannot simply be cities, because that doesn't let you model the cost of switching from one line to another within a city.  Each node must be a *pair* consisting of a city number and a bus line number, representing the bus line you are currently riding on.  The bus line number can be -1 to represent that you are not on a bus, and the starting and destination nodes would have a bus line numbers of -1.

Then each edge would represent either the cost of staying on the line you are currently on to ride to the next city, or getting off the bus in your current city (which is free), or getting on a bus line within your current city (which has the transfer cost).

You said the cities are numbered from 0 to n but I see a bunch of loops that stop at `n - 1` (because they use `< n` as the loop condition), so that might be another problem.